# Unable to Connect C# Application to MSSQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm writing a C# application in visual studio 2015.

I'm trying to connect to a remote (off-site) sql 2008 server I have tried the following:

**Remote Server Connections are open**

**Server was already configured with no TCP port.. the port line is blank.. in fact the firewall is turned off.**

I can connect remotely (via remote desktop) and access the server on the given IP address.

Connection String - IP, Username, Password removed for obvious reasons:

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mssqlConnBtn.Text = "Connecting..";
        try
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=#.#.#.#\\DC3\\POS,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=bDatabase;User ID=[username];Password=[password]";
            conn.Open();
            mssqlConnBtn.Text = "Connected";
        }
        catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException exsql)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exsql.Message);
            mssqlConnBtn.Text = "Connect";
        }
    }
```

I have also tried `Data Source=#.#.#.#,1433`

Error:

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.

The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.

(provider: TCP Provider, Error:0 - The wait operation timed out.)
```

Any ideas here?

Thanks!

Comment: "C# application in visual basic 2015" - I'm sure that should be Visual Studio 2015?

Comment: Are you using same server name to connect it with SQL Server Management Studio? If yes then just for try add Persist Security Info=True;  into your connection string

Comment: @AnkitkumarBhatt Yes, I'm using the same connection info. I'm still getting the same error when I try: `conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=#.#.#.#\\DC3\\POS,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=bDatabase;User ID=[username];Password=[password]";`

Comment: try to get connection string from the visual studio server explorer, I think that one would be the correct one

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you have 2 instance names there. Try the following:

```
"Data Source=#.#.#.#\InstanceName,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=bDatabase;User ID=[username];Password=[password]"
```

You may not even need the instance name - if this is your default instance try the following:

```
"Data Source=#.#.#.#,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=bDatabase;User ID=[username];Password=[password]"
```

Comment: Neither of these work. When I connect in Management Studio I use server name `DC3\POS`, would this matter?

Comment: You could also try "Data Source=DC3\POS;Initial Catalog=bDatabase;User ID=[username];Password=[password]" if DC3 is your server name.

Comment: It's a remote server. That wouldn't work unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

A good trick is to create an empty text file, rename it `connection.udl`, double click it -> a "Data Link Properties" dialog opens:

[image: Data Link Properties]

Fill in everything & press <kbd>Test Connection</kbd> until it works. Then press <kbd>OK</kbd>.

Afterwards the `.udl` file will contain your connection string.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=#.#.#.#\\DC3\\POS,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=bDatabase;User ID=[username];Password=[password]";
```

Try

```
conn.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=#.#.#.#\DC3;Initial Catalog=bDatabase;User ID=[username];Password=[password]";
```

1433 is the default port, can be ommited safely.
If you are using the IP address, DBMSSOCN can be ommited.

I think your problems is your instance name. AFAIK, instance names do not contain '\' character, so "\DC3\POS" seems wrong to me.

Edit: Confirmed, it is the instance string. Cannot contain backslashes.

Source: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143744(v=sql.90).aspx

" Instance names are not case sensitive.

Instance names cannot contain the terms Default, MSSQLServer, or other reserved keywords. If a reserved keyword is used in an instance name, an error will occur.

Instance names are limited to 16 characters.

The first character in the instance name must be a letter or an underscore (_). Acceptable letters are those defined by the Unicode Standard 2.0, including Latin characters a-z and A-Z, and letter characters from other languages.

Subsequent characters can be letters defined by the Unicode Standard 2.0, decimal numbers from Basic Latin or other national scripts, the dollar sign ($), or an underscore (_).

Embedded spaces of other special characters are not allowed in instance names, nor are the backslash (), comma (,), colon (:), semi-colon (;), single quotation mark ('), ampersand (&), number sign (#), or at sign (@)."

Comment: Thanks the the help. Unfortunately, I get the error:  `A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I tried: `conn.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=#.#.#.#\DC3;Initial Catalog=bDatabase;User ID=[username];Password=[password]";` and `conn.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=#.#.#.#\POS;Initial Catalog=bDatabase;User ID=[username];Password=[password]";`  both not working.. hmm..

Comment: You may also want to check if remote connections are enabled on your server. (e.g. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/walzenbach/2010/04/14/how-to-enable-remote-connections-in-sql-server-2008/)

Comment: Or SQL Server browser service is running on the server.

Comment: @DennisZiegan As stated in my question above, remote connections are enabled.

Comment: @bradbury9 Just checked, that service is running.

Comment: I would get a message if it was something to do with user permissions, correct?

Comment: `Data Source=#.#.#.#\\DC3\\POS,1433` is wrong... Cannot be "DC3\POS"